# Convert One Key Value from List of Dictionaries to List

Tags: python, django, postgresql, dictionary, django-orm

I have a list of dictionaries that is encoded:

```
[u"{'name':'Tom', 'uid':'asdlfkj223'}", u"{'name':'Jerry', 'uid':'alksd32'}", ...]
```

Is there anyway I can create a list of just the values of the key name?

Even better if someone knows Django ORM well enough to pull down a list of a data/column with properties from a PostgreSQL database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only that value for the `name` column from the DB table, use:

```
names = Person.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

(as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list)

otherwise, given

```
people = [{'name':'Tom', 'uid':'asdlfkj223'}, {'name':'Jerry', 'uid':'alksd32'},]
```

this should do the job:

```
names = [person['name'] for person in people]
```

And you should find out why your data items are strings (containing a string representation of a dict) to start with—it doesn't look like the way it's supposed to be.

Or, if you're actually storing `dict`'s in your database as strings, either prefer JSON over the Python string representation, or if you must use the current format, the AST parsing solution provided in another question here should do the job.

Comment: They aren't dictionaries though. They're strings

Comment: Yeah, that's something he probably needs to fix first—doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an optimal situation that I was placed into.  Thanks for the help.  I actually tried both of the approaches you mentioned but storing strings like that is a headache and causes errors.

Comment: So did my answer solve your problem? Or answer the posed question?

Comment: No, actually they didn't work.  Even the ast.literal_eval is throwing up a malformed error.  This model is not optimal.  Putting strings as dictionary values is not great.

Comment: I think the point is that if the ask **question** was answered, an answer should be accepted—if it turned out that your problem is elsewhere, it doesn't mean that the **quesiton** wasn't answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> data = [u"{'name':'Tom', 'uid':'asdlfkj223'}",u"{'name':'Jerry', 'uid':'alksd32'}"]
>>> import ast
>>> [ast.literal_eval(d)['name'] for d in data]
['Tom', 'Jerry']
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `ast.literal_eval` over the regular `eval`?

Comment: @jbaiter `ast.literal_eval` is **much** safer than using eval. [Here's](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) a link to the docs

Comment: @jbaiter: `eval` is unsafe and it's rarely a good idea to use it. `ast.literal_eval` is safe for this purpose.